# How to split a list, if possible?? (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can any one tell me how to split a list, if its possible. Want to split it word by word.

my list contains links like:

```
 ['14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade']
```

Now, i want to use the split method, to split up 14th_century and 15th_century, so it is 2 words, and so on with all links.

So for every sign " ; " it should just split it.

right now i made a for loop.

```
for line in loops:
```

UPDATE:

have done it so far as this.

```
links = []    
for line in newPath:
    links.append(line[3:4])

old_list = []
new_list = []

old_list = links
new_list = old_list[0].split(';')

print new_list
```

Comment: What is your definition of word (stream of characters separated by underscrores ?)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
my_list = old_list[0].split(';')
```

#### Examples

```
>>> old_list = ['14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade']

>>> my_list = old_list[0].split(';')
['14th_century', '15th_century', '16th_century', 'Pacific_Ocean', 'Atlantic_Ocean', 'Accra', 'Africa', 'Atlantic_slave_trade', 'African_slave_trade']
```

Comment: Then i get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @pixel, Are you sure you did `old_list[0]` and not just `old_list` since your string is in a list in your question

Comment: Have added new code in top

Comment: @Pixel, Note, your old_list should be a list of length 1 which contains one long string as shown by the first code in your question.

Comment: @pixel, please my example in my answer

Comment: but i want to do it for the whole list (links) which contains alot links, 20000+

thats why i tried set old_list = links in start

Comment: @Pixel, In that case just do: `for my_str in old_list:` and then my line above or something like that. You can adapt it to fit your problem.

Comment: @Pixel This is the correct answer for the example that you posted (a list with sole string element). If your list looks actually different you should post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
paths = ['abc;def;ghi', 'jkl;mno;pqr']
paths = [path.split(';') for path in paths]
>>> paths
[['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr']]
```

Comment: also give me same error, 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Given that paths is a list of strings. Check my answer again for an example.